# androidx fragment.app FragmentStatePagerAdapter is deprecated (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have checked a lot of sites to solve this problem but my problem is not solved .

I'm trying to make a ViewPager by using the fragment . but when I was trying to use it , I realized that it deprecated
What am I supposed to do now ?

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager)
    {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }
    });
```

Comment: migrate to ViewPager2

Answer (score 0):

This class is deprecated.

**Switch to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 and use androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter instead.**

do follow this,
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#summary